# Bash if statement outputs "no such file or directory" when comparing a variable to a choice

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I have a file named `main.sh`, which acts as a launcher for other shell scripts.

*contents of main.sh*

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "  -----------------------------------------------"
echo " /                                               \\"
echo "|              Welcome to myprogram               |"
echo " \\                                               /"
echo "  -----------------------------------------------"
echo 
echo 
echo "1: Ping"

read -p "What is your choice ? " choice


if $choice = "1"
then
    echo "Launching Ping"
    ./netscrubber/ping.sh

else
    # Bad number
    echo "There's no tool with number $choice"
    read -p "Please try again. Quitting, clear screen ? [y/n, default n]" isclear
    
    $isclear=${isclear:-n}

    if $isclear="y"
    then
        echo "Exiting and clearing..."
        sleep 1
        echo "4"
        sleep 1
        echo "3"
        sleep 1
        echo "2"
        sleep 1
        echo "1"
        sleep 1
        clear
        exit
    else
    echo "Exititng without clearing."
    exit
    fi
fi
```

Basically, if i type a number that is not in the list, it goes to the `# Bad Number` section.

I run `main.sh`, choose 5 (a bad number, which will go to the `# bad number tag`, which results in

```
./main.sh: line 16: 5: command not found
```

Also, the clear after a bad number foes not work. If i type Y when

```
Please try again. Quitting, clear screen ? [y/n, default n]
```

is on the screen, i should get:

```
Exiting and clearing
4
3
2
1
```

and then a clear.

I get

```
Please try again. Quitting, clear screen ? [y/n, default n]y
./main.sh: line 25: y=y: command not found
./main.sh: line 27: y=y: command not found
Exititng without clearing.
```

which is behaviour that answering `n` should do (minus the errors)

Any help would be much appreciated.

### Steps to reproduce

I run `main.sh`, choose 5 (a bad number, which will go to the `# bad number tag`, which results in

```
./main.sh: line 16: 5: command not found
```

The `read` input should not be treated as a command, rather an input into the `$choice` variable.

It, however passes onto to `# Bad number`, just throws an error.

However, the clear after a bad number does not work. If i type Y when

```
Please try again. Quitting, clear screen ? [y/n, default n]
```

is on the screen, i should get:

```
Exiting and clearing
4
3
2
1
```

and then a clear.

I get

```
Please try again. Quitting, clear screen ? [y/n, default n]y
./main.sh: line 25: y=y: command not found
./main.sh: line 27: y=y: command not found
Exititng without clearing.
```

which answering `n` should do, minus the errors

Comment: There should be spaces around the `=` in `if $isclear="y"`.

Comment: Place your script on https://www.shellcheck.net/# to check for common bash mistakes

Comment: Have a look at the bash man page about the syntax of the `if` statement. Its form is `if COMMAND`, and the _if_  takes the _then_-branch, if _COMMAND_ sets exit code 0. `$choice = "1"` tries to run the command `$choice` - in your case `5` - with the arguments `=` and `1`.  Since you don't have a command `5` in your PATH, you get the error message _command not foun_.

Comment: Useful commands for testing the value of a variable in bash are `test`, `[[ ... ]]` and `(( ... ))`. If we know that a variable contains an number, `if (( choice == 1 ))` would test it. In any case, please make yourself familiar with those test commands before your use them in your scripts.

Comment: I also don't understand, why you tagged the question as _zsh_, when you are using _bash_.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the question:

https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2283 is the correct article from shellcheck. Thanks @0stone0 for introducing me to shellcheck. Thanks to @user193448 for explaining.

`if $choice = 1` turned into `if [[ $choice = 1 ]]`, which compares `$choice` to 1. The 1st one tried to execute the contents of `$choice` as a filename or command. Since the contents of `$choice` were not in my path as a command, it didn't work.

Thanks for reading !

EDIT : Thanks to @CharlesDuffy for explaining to me that i should either double bracket (`[[ $choice = 1 ]]`) or quote my variable (`[ "$choice" = 1 ]`)

Comment: To be more comprehensively correct, you should either quote -- as in, `[ "$choice" = 1 ]` -- or switch to extended syntax `[[ $choice = 1 ]]`. Without the quotes, you'll get surprising behaviors if, say `choice` is completely empty, or if it contains more than one word. (BTW, shellcheck should point the quoting problem out too).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for explaining. i will proceed to edit the question

Comment: Ideally, it should only be the answer, as opposed to the question, being edited on the above point -- we want questions, even when edited for clarity, to still show the problem so answers attached to them make sense. (also, `$isclear=${isclear:-n}` should be `isclear=${isclear:-n}` -- the `$` is an expansion operator, not part of the variable name)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry, i didn't re-read my comment, yes, i edited my awnser, not the question. Also, the `shellcheck` utility helped my with the second point. Thank you!

Comment: Good that you fixed it, just a suggestion, if you want use to just compare

I would suggest, unless you need numeric operation, this is safe even if $choice is empty you will not get error.

``` 
if [ "$choice" = "1" ] 
```